# Error using caffe Unknown command 'get_weights'

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, caffe

I run the demo code of [RCNN](https://github.com/rbgirshick/rcnn) with matcaffe, but I met an error which confused me for a while:

```
Error using caffe
Unknown command 'get_weights'

Error in rcnn_load_model (line 36)
rcnn_model.cnn.layers = caffe('get_weights');
```

Also, I check the directory of [caffe matlab](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/matlab/%2Bcaffe), there is not `get_weights` function. Do anyone know how to solve that? Thank you.

Comment: You're asking a question about a github repository, I don't know how few people have seen before. You should contact the authors of that package.

Comment: Did you follow the exact instructions on the [RCNN](https://github.com/rbgirshick/rcnn), particullary regarding the version of Caffe supported?

Comment: Thank you. Yeah. I know the caffe version is 0.999. I cannot build it with newer version, am I right?

Comment: Probably, I haven't used this tool myself. Caffe most likely changed.